# Webcrawling webpages using python charm

Tags: python, web-crawler

[enter image description here][1]Id like to scrape a web page for the name of subject and words find all words for a word i decide to search within the web page. My code so far not working

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
start_urls = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_science'
r = requests.get(start_urls)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
crawled_page =[]
for page in soup.findAll('data'):
  crawled_page.append(page.get('href'))
print(crawled_page


Errormessage:
C:\Users\tette\PycharmProjects\WebcrawlerProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
C:/Users/tette/PycharmProjects/WebcrawlerProject/webScrapy/webScrapy/spiders
```

/webcrawler.py
    []

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text in question, not image, and not in comment. Python can't load image to run code - so we can't test it and can't create modifications. Downvote.

Comment: `findAll('data')` is searching tag `<data...>` but it is not HTML tag.

Comment: if you want to find word `data` in text then you need rather `.findAll(string=re.compile("data"))`

Comment: How do i fix that?

Comment: is 're' in a package i have to import? because im getting an error message

Comment: `import re` - it is regex module (regular expression)

Comment: _Errormessage:_ That doesn't look like an error message, though? _Process finished with exit code 0_ Does the program throw an error, or does it run?

Comment: it runs but nothing prints

Comment: it prints nothing because it searchs tag `<data>` which doesn't exists in HTML. See doc for [findAll](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) - first argument searchs only tags.

Comment: @Brian1234 _It runs but nothing prints_ Then your post should make that clear, no?

Comment: My apologies.it runa but nothing prints out

Answer (score 1):

if you want to search word in text then you should use

```
import re

soup.findAll(string=re.compile('data'))
```

but it finds strings (`NavigableString`), not tags, so you may have to get they parent to search attributes like `href`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
import re

start_urls = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_science'

r = requests.get(start_urls)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
crawled_page =[]
for page in soup.findAll(string=re.compile('data')):
    #print(isinstance(page, NavigableString))
    #print(page.parent)
    href = page.parent.get('href')
    if href: # skip None
        crawled_page.append(href)
print(crawled_page)
```

---

**EDIT:** similar with `lxml` using `xpath`

```
import requests
import lxml.html
import re

start_urls = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_science'

r = requests.get(start_urls)

soup = lxml.html.fromstring(r.content)

crawled_page =[]

for page in soup.xpath('//*[contains(text(), "data")]'):
    href = page.attrib.get('href')
    if href: # skip None
        crawled_page.append(href)

print(crawled_page)
```

Comment: got an error message:C:\Users\tette\PycharmProjects\WebcrawlerProject\venv\Scripts\python.exeC:/Users/tette/PycharmProjects/WebcrawlerProject/webScrapy/webScrapy/spiders/webcrawler.py
Traceback (most recent call last): "C:/Users/tette/PycharmProjects/WebcrawlerProject/webScrapy/webScrapy/spiders/webcrawler.py", line 14, in <module>
    crawled_page.append(page.get('href')) File "C:\Users\tette\PycharmProjects\WebcrawlerProject\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 871, in __getattr__self.__class__.__name__, attr))
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: see code - there is `.parent` in my code `page.parent.get('href')` - because `findAll(string=re.compile('data'))` finds text inside tags, not tags, and text doesn't have attributes like `href` and it needs to get parent element which is tag and it has attributes like `href`.